# How to allow window background service to access SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, windows, authentication, windows-services

I have background service which access my SQL Server database.

My background service working fine when I try to get a row from SQL Server database 
I get an exception

> base {System.Data.Common.DbException} = 
>   {"Cannot open database \"test2\"
>   requested by the login. The login
>   failed.\r\nLogin failed  for user 'NT
>   AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE'."}**

`test2` is my database name.

How do I allow my background service to access SQL Server database?

Comment: Most likely, you need to a) create a specific login on your SQL Server, b) a specific user in your database, and c) use that specific user in your connection string to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[grant](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172405.aspx) user `NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE` access to the database

Comment: That would grant access to all services. Apparently it is also possible to grant access to a specific service: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/using-service-sids-to-grant-permissions-to-services-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15