# Test Quartz.NET connectivity to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, quartz.net

I have my Quartz.net windows service running, and configured the SQL Server tables and connectivity in the quartz.config file for ADOJobStore.  Is there any way to test that quartz can access SQL without having to create jobs, etc.?  Also, the examples I've seen use a connection string that includes username and password. We use integrated security instead. Is that possible? (Which is why I want to test connectivity without wasting time setting up jobs, etc...if Quartz can't use integrated security in a SQL Svr connection string then it's a no go for us using Quartz.)

Comment: As soon as QuartzServer is started, it sends select queries to the QRTZ_TRIGGERS table every second to see if any triggers are pending.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer my own question hoping this will help someone else.

If your connectivity is configured correctly, Quartz will automatically write some rows to QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS and QRTZ_LOCKS (and a few others).

And yes, integrated security seems to work.  I used this:
Data Source=MyServer;Initial Catalog=ABC;Integrated Security=SSPI;
which is very standard and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to test that quartz can access SQL without having to create jobs, etc.?

Something like

```
  var groups = scheduler.GetJobGroupNames().ToList();
```

should throw an exception if you can't connect.

> Also, the examples I've seen use a connection string that includes username and password. We use integrated security instead. Is that possible?

Quartz.net support any valid sql connection string including integrated security. But if you try this and you are not running your service under a user account, you may have take extra steps to configure your sql server. (See [How to allow window background service to access SQL Server database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607742/how-to-allow-window-background-service-to-access-sql-server-database))